# Commands out of sync; you can't run this now

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a query on mysql with a subquery in the SELECT clause and I got this error: #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
I haven't been able to solve it. Can you help me please?

```
SELECT e.IdDocumento, e.CveDistrito, d.STCT_NOM, e.CveJuzgado, j.CTJU_DESCR, e.NumDocumento, e.IdRamoDocumento, r.Descripcion....., (SELECT pd.nombre FROM ParteDocumento AS pd WHERE pd.IdDocumento = e.IdDocumento) AS NombreActor  
FROM Documentos AS e 
INNER JOIN CtRamo AS r ON ( r.IdRamo = e.IdRamoDocumento ) 
INNER JOIN CtEstado AS edo ON ( edo.CveEstado = e.CveEstado ) 
INNER JOIN CTDISJUD AS d ON (d.STCT_NUM = e.CveDistrito) 
INNER JOIN CTJUZGAD AS j ON (j.CTJU_MUNIC = e.CveDistrito AND j.CTJU_JUZGA = e.CveJuzgado) 
LEFT JOIN CtMedioPresentacion AS m ON ( m.IdMedioPresentacion = e.IdMedioPresentacion ) 
WHERE e.IdTipoDocumento =1 AND e.EsRecibido =1
```

This is my query. I did the same query in SQL Server and it works!

Comment: How/where are you calling this query?  See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commands-out-of-sync.html) for more information.

Comment: as @TimBiegeleisen has suggested, this is not something to do with your query but something to do with your programming language code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but i think you can not use table from `from` clause in a subselect inside of `select`. But why not simply join the table instead of subselect:

```
SELECT e.IdDocumento, e.CveDistrito, d.STCT_NOM, e.CveJuzgado, j.CTJU_DESCR, e.NumDocumento, e.IdRamoDocumento, r.Descripcion....., pd.nombreNombreActor  
FROM Documentos AS e 
INNER JOIN CtRamo AS r ON ( r.IdRamo = e.IdRamoDocumento ) 
INNER JOIN CtEstado AS edo ON ( edo.CveEstado = e.CveEstado ) 
INNER JOIN CTDISJUD AS d ON (d.STCT_NUM = e.CveDistrito) 
INNER JOIN CTJUZGAD AS j ON (j.CTJU_MUNIC = e.CveDistrito AND j.CTJU_JUZGA = e.CveJuzgado) 
LEFT JOIN CtMedioPresentacion AS m ON ( m.IdMedioPresentacion = e.IdMedioPresentacion )
LEFT JOIN ParteDocumento as pd on pd.IdDocumento = e.IdDocumento
WHERE e.IdTipoDocumento =1 AND e.EsRecibido =1
```